# Pure ruby UK phone number validator

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to implement a pure Ruby phone number validator for the UK's number. There are a lot of topics related to phone validation but most of them use regex which I want to avoid (mainly because it's unreadable). I'm aware of [phone_validator_gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/validates_phone_number) but frankly I don't want to use any additional gems.

Let's make these assumptions:

- any perfix format allowed (+447..., 447..., 07...)
- UK phone numbers are 11 digits long when in the 07... format and always have 7 after the prefix (whether it's +44, 44 or 0)

The implemented module should do:

- removes any spaces from number
- check it is valid (raises an error if not)
- outputs it in the +447... format

E.g. I call format with `071234 56789` as the input, it should return `+447123456789`. If I call it with 063434, it should raise an error.

I've no idea is there any way to avoid regex? What I did so far is just simple removing whitespaces and check if it's 11 digits.long, my module below:

```
module Uk
  VALID_PREFIX = '+447'

  def self.format(number)
    clear_format = number.delete(' ')

    return clear_format if clear_format.delete('^0-9').length == 11 && clear_format[0, 4].includes?(VALID_PREFIX)

  end
end
```

Comment: Why avoid regex? If you consider them "unreadable", the solution is not to avoid an entire class of solution, but to learn to read them. As much as I'm not one to promote regular expressions where they are not needed, they're not to be generally avoided in all cases, and matching patterns in text is their bread and butter.

Comment: phone_number_validator is a tiny gem with basically no dependencies. It's a thin wrapper around [a few regexes](https://github.com/travisjeffery/validates_phone_number/blob/master/lib/validates_phone_number/formats.rb). You're going to wind up recreating this work, might as well use the gem if it works.

Comment: On the topic of the code you've written so far: `.delete('^0-9')` does nothing. You've given it a string that looks like a regex, but that doesn't actually do what your codes implies you think it does. It needs an actual regex, ie `delete(/[^0-9]/)`, but this will allow strings like `foo0000foo000foo0000` to pass, when you specifically say invlaid input should raise an error. Also `.length(11)` raises an exception;  you want `.length == 11`.  You're also using `.include?` where a simple `==` would suffice.

Comment: @meagar I agree with you but `.delete('^0-9')` works well - it removes all characters except integers.

Comment: Hey, you're absolutely right. That's surprising to me, but it's always fun to learn something new in Ruby.

Comment: @mrmuscle: Your `return ... if ....` does not make sense. If the `if` condition does not evaluate to trueish, your method would return `nil`. Just do a `clear_format.delete(.....)` unconditionally, and always return `clear_format` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid gems and regexes, you're doing Rails in hard mode. I would strongly suggest you devote some time to getting comfortable with both.

[Parsing phone numbers is always more complicated than you think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom). For example, your assumption that "*UK phone numbers are 11 digits long when in the 07... format and always have 7 after the prefix (whether it's +44, 44 or 0)*" is not correct. 07 is just a really common prefix.

It's best to leave it as someone else's problem, so if there's a gem use it. For example, [`uk-phone-number-formatter`](https://github.com/jwon114/uk-phone-number-formatter) seems to do exactly what you want and [it is tiny](https://github.com/jwon114/uk-phone-number-formatter/blob/master/lib/formatter/phone_number/uk.rb).

---

Let's say we do this without regexes and without gems and assume 07 is the only prefix. First, separate the problem into two steps.

1. Normalization
2. Validation

Normalization is reformatting the phone number so that equivalent phone numbers look the same. Validation is validating its a phone number. Validation is much easier if the data has already been normalized.

That means stripping everything that isn't a digit, fixing the prefx, and adding the `+` at the front.

Stripping everything that isn't a digit is easy with [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.4/String.html#method-i-gsub): `phone.gsub!(/\D+/)`. Or the non-regex [`delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-delete): `phone.delete('^0-9')`.

Now with non-numbers out of the way, we just want to change "07" into "447".

Finally, add the `+`.

```
def normalize(phone)
  # Strip non-digits.
  normalized = phone.delete('^0-9')

  # Replace 07x with 447x  
  if normalized[0..1] == "07"
    normalized[0] = "44"
  end

  # Add the plus.
  return "+#{normalized}"
end
```

Now that it's normalized, validation is easy.

```
# We assume the phone number is validated.
def phone_is_uk_format(phone)
  errors.add(:phone, :missing_prefx, message: "Missing +447 prefix")
    if normalized[0..3] != "+447"

  # 12 because of the leading +
  errors.add(:phone, :wrong_length, message: "A phone number is 11 digits")
    if normalized.length != 12
end
```

And integrating it with a model...

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validate :phone_is_uk_format

  # Normalize the phone number when it is set.
  def phone=(number)
    super(normalize_uk_phone(number))
  end

  private def phone_is_uk_format
    # Validating presence is different.
    return if phone.blank?

    errors.add(:phone, :missing_prefx, message: "Missing +447 prefix")
      if phone[0..3] != "+447"

    # 12 because of the leading +
    errors.add(:phone, :wrong_length, message: "A phone number is 11 digits")
      if phone.length != 12
  end

  private def normalize_uk_phone(phone)
    # Strip non-digits.
    normalized = phone.delete('^0-9')

    # Replace 07x with 447x  
    if normalized[0..1] == "07"
      normalized[0] = "44"
    end

    # Add the plus.
    return "+#{normalized}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I have a tiny suggestion. In fact, it's so tiny that it's probably not worth mentioning. Yes, too tiny.